# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in #0 {main} thrown in on line 7

Tags: php, pdo

I got fatal error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\sonu\PDO\test.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sonu\PDO\test.php on line 7

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;root', 'test', '');

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sonu");

while($row = $query->fetch())
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are not selecting a database, your dsn string looks wrong. What is `root` supposed to do?

Comment: `mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PDO constructor is wrong. You are not declaring the database to which the PDO instance should connect to.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;root', 'test', '');
```

The DSN should have the database name and the host name. You have `root` at the end of it which should not be there.

The line above should be like so:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbnamehere', 'test', '');
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) in the future and check that your code corresponds with it.

Comment: may be db name is `test`. And username is `root`. I guess. Not sure ...:p

Comment: Possibly, OP should be aware of it now when he sees the documentation if that is the case.